# product of two definite integrals with different contours

Tags: integration

Given an arbitrary equation f(x), it is wanted to find 
$$ ( \int_0^{x1} f(x)dx ) * (\int_0^{x2} g(x)dx) $$

is there a way to maybe get rid of the contours so that the product is like the product of integrals by definition?

Comment: I don't know what "contours" you are talking about but the first thing I would do is use different letters to represent the two different "variables of integration": $\left(\int_0^{x_1}f(x)dx\right)\left(\int_0^{x_1}g(y)dy\right)$ and that product is equal to the double integral[tex]\int_0^{x_1}\int_0^{x_2} f(x)g(y)dydx$

Comment: they are the same variables of integration though. Both f and g are arbitrary equations function of x.

Comment: contour is the limits of the definite integrals. they are different.

Comment: No, those are "dummy variables"- the "x" in $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ has no meaning outside the itegral: $\int_a^b f(x)dx= \int_a^b f(y)dy= \int_a^b f(x)dx= \int_a^b f(z)dz$ etc.